# Separate hostname and path in cURL

Tags: curl

Is there a way to separate the hostname and path when using cURL? I would like to make a request to the server itself, not on a particular resource, as described below by IETF:

> The four options for Request-URI are dependent on the nature of the
> request. The asterisk "*" means that the request does not apply to a
> particular resource, but to the server itself, and is only allowed
> when the method used does not necessarily apply to a resource. One
> example would be
>
> ```
>   OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
> ```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2

Similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12323445/594696