# curl CONNECT method without path (destination hostname and port instead)

Tags: http, curl

I want to test proxy server. In order to make https request, browser sends CONNECT method beforehand (e.g. like Firefox does, when proxy is specified).
I can not achieve/send the same result in `curl`:

Following has root slash `/www.example.com:443`:

```
curl -X CONNECT http://proxy_host:proxy_port/www.example.com:443
```

Following will not work (without slash):

```
curl -X CONNECT http://proxy_host:proxy_portwww.example.com:443
```

Following is not what I want:

```
curl -X CONNECT http://proxy_host:proxy_port/some_path
```

So the first line of HTTP data [should be](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT) `CONNECT www.example.com:443 HTTP/1.1` but not `CONNECT /www.example.com:443 HTTP/1.1` like curl sends in this case.

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423999/separate-hostname-and-path-in-curl) also related some-how, if I would know how to not send path.

**NOTE!** I do not want to use `curl -x http://proxy_host:proxy_port https://www.example.com`, because this option/flag `-x` does not work with custom SSL certificates `--cacert ... --key ... --cert ...`.

Any ideas how to send plain header data or not specify path, or specify host and port as a path?

Answer (score 6):

(`-X` simply replaces the string in the request so of course setting it to `CONNECT` will not issue a proper CONNECT request and will certainly not make curl handle it correctly.)

curl will do a CONNECT by itself when connecting to a TLS server through a HTTP proxy, and even though you claim `-x` breaks the certificate options that is an incorrect statement. The `--cacert` and other options work the same even when the connection is done through a HTTP proxy.

You can also make curl do a CONNECT trough a HTTP(S) proxy for other protocols by using `-p, --proxytunnel` - also in combination with `-x`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a bit late, but anyway, I'm posting it just in case anyone face the same problem.

You can change the `target` of the request manually with `--request-target`, see [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html). So the correct command should be:

```bash
curl -X CONNECT http://proxy_host:proxy_port --request-target www.example.com:443 -H 'Host: www.example.com:443'
```

Tested on Debian:

```
$ curl -v -X CONNECT http://172.17.80.1:7890 --request-target www.google.com:443 -H 'Host: www.google.com:443'
*   Trying 172.17.80.1:7890...
* Connected to 172.17.80.1 (172.17.80.1) port 7890 (#0)
> CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
<
* Closing connection 0
```